# Left and Right limits of $\lfloor\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor$ at $x = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I'm self-studying calculus from Larson's Calculus 8E and on page 102 and I don't understand why

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{\lfloor\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor - 0}{x} = \infty $$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x-0} = \frac{\lfloor\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor- 0}{x} = 0 $$

Why isn't the first limit 0? Why is the second limit not $\infty$?

Comment: What function is $[[x]]$?

Comment: did you mean floor function? $$ [[x]]$$

Comment: I meant greatest integer function, I didn't know how to format it, sorry.

Comment: @EdwardK: I edited the question. greatest integer function=floor function $\lfloor x\rfloor$. see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html).

Comment: Examples like this are no way to teach calculus to non-mathematicians.  But it's widely done.  That's why so many get grades of "A+" in that subject without ever finding out what it's about.

Answer (score 1):

For the first, note that for $-1\lt x\lt 0$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=-1$, so $\lfloor\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor=-1$.

For the second, note that for $0\lt x\lt 1$, $\lfloor x\rfloor=0$, so $\lfloor\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\frac{-1}{x}$ for $x<0$ and $\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=0$ for $x>0$.

Can you take it from here?